# Heroku App Crashes - Reports Error in ActiveSupport gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, heroku, activesupport

I'm having some hard time running my app on Heroku - The app runs perfect on my local machine. :(
The logs report some problem with my ActiveSupport gem. So, i've taken these measures:

1) Re-installed ActiveSupport gem
2) Rolled back my Git commit to a previous one which was working fine.
3) Copied my app to a new folder - Created a new Git Repo, did `bundle install` in new folder, Made Commits, Added Heroku remote origin, pushed app to Heroku - didn't helped.

My Rails Version: 3.0.3
Ruby: 1.8.7

Here is my Heroku Log (Updated)

Surprisingly enough i'm getting 1.9.1 after ./bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1 whereas the project is using Ruby 1.8.7. Any ideas how i can fix this?

```
    2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:304:in `rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- errors_helper (LoadError)
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `depend_on'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:216:in `require_dependency'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `each'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `block in eager_load!'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `each'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `eager_load!'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `eval'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
2011-07-08T00:42:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, I've fixed this thing. And i feel like throwing myself from the tallest building in the world for this. I've been struggling with this since the last week.

There was a file in my `app/helpers` directory called `errors_helper.rb` which was unfortunately named `errors_helper.rb.rb`

Changing the name extension solved my problem!

Comment: I got the same problem and I could not find the errors_helper.rb.rb . I think there is something wrong which is not related to the wrong file name. It may related to the conflict Rails and ruby gems.

Comment: If you didn't realized by now - This was a problem that was occurring in my environment alone. You might be having some different issue. If you were being Sarcastic - you were not sarcastic enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rails 3x, you should be using rubygems 1.9.2, not 1.8.7. Also make sure you have your correct rails version declared in your environment.rb if you are on rails 2x as well as your Gemfile.

So for rails 2x project

environment.rb

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.8' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '2.3.8'
```

and for rails 3x project

Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
```

That way heroku knows which rails version to load under which gem sets. You should be able to

```
git push heroku master
```

if it is all straightened out

Comment: Hello Chris, I already have that defined in appropriate files.

Comment: as a side note, Rails 3.x works fine on Ruby 1.8.7 - Ruby 1.9.2 is not a requirement for Rails 3.x